# skip counting by 10 with help of for loop

Tags: julia

I would like to get the following values `1, 10, 20, 30, ...` but I do not how to do it Julia:

```
 for (count, x) in enumerate(["x1", "x1.y1", "x1.y1.xyz22", "x133001", "x133001.y1", "x133001.y1.xyz22"])
     println(count + 10 - 1)
 end
```

What would the best way?

Thank you in advance,

**Update**

```
The below code failed to run:

julia> count = 1
1

julia> for x in ["x1", "x1.y1", "x1.y1.xyz22", "x133001", "x133001.y1", "x133001.y1.xyz22"]
           if count == 1
               count = 10
           else
               count += 10
           println(count)
       end


ERROR: syntax: incomplete: "for" at REPL[6]:1 requires end
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:0
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 0,10,20... Or 1,11,21...? Otherwise, I'm not fully sure what pattern you want.

Comment: I would like to have `1,10,20, 30, ..`

Comment: `println(1); foreach(println, 10:10:1000)`, or however high you want to go. If you want infinite, you can write a `while` loop and increment `count += 10` at each iteration.

Comment: @DNF it's a pitty that `a = 10:10:Inf` doesn't work because `Inf` is only float and there isn't an integer representation of infinite..

Comment: If that is what you want, use `Iterators.countfrom(10, 10)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of an indefinite number of exact solutions. With (count, x) you can mostly use count but use x for the start and end cases:

```
for (count, x) in enumerate(
    ["x1", "x1.y1", "x1.y1.xyz22", "x133001", "x133001.y1", "x133001.y1.xyz22"]
    )
    if x == "x1"
        print(count, ", ")
    else
        print(10 * (count - 1), ", ")
    end
    if x == "x133001.y1.xyz22"
        println("...")
    end
 end
```

Gets you:   `1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, ...`

Answer (score 1):

For inifinite streams one could use Python-like generators which are available in `ResumableFunctions.jl` package.

Install by:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("ResumableFunctions")
using ResumableFunctions
```

Generate an inifnite stream generator function:

```
@resumable function infstream(start = 0, first_val = 0, step=1)
  "It starts with start value steps by step. However, for first value    
   first_val is returned."
  c = start
  while 1==1
    @yield if (c==start) first_val else c end
    c = c + step
  end
end
```

You initialize an instance by:

```
mycount = infstream(0, 1, 10)
mycount() # 1
mycount() # 10
mycount() # 20
# ... etc ad infinitum
```

For your problem you can use it like this:

```
counter, result = infstream(0, 1, 10), []
for x in ["x1", "x1.y1", "x1.y1.xyz22", "x133001", "x133001.y1", "x133001.y1.xyz22"]
    push!(result, counter())
end
```

which gives:

```
julia> result
6-element Array{Any,1}:
  1
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50
```

With the resumable `infstream()` function, you can create any thinkable counters for arithmetic inifinite series.